# Por que o stackoverflow em português não tem área de empregos?

Tags: novo-recurso

Apesar de ter feito essa conta há algum tempo, somente recentemente comecei a utilizá-la ativamente. Antes usava apenas o stackoverflow em inglês. Hoje notei que não existe a aba de empregos (jobs) no stackoverflow PT. Alguém sabe o porquê?

Abaixo mostro a imagem de como essa aba aparece no stackoverflow-eng:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que nenhuma outra comunidade StackOverflow tem isso, só o SO inglês

Comment: Se tivermos como objetivo atrair mais pessoas para a comunidade, seria legal ter essa opção no stack PT. O Brasil e PT tem muitos bons programadores, mas creio que eles façam mais uso do stackoverflow em ENG. Acho muito importante o trabalho que vem sendo feito até aqui no stack PT porque, na prática, esse é um trabalho de inclusão que dá acesso a uma ferramenta de aprendizado incrível para pessoas que não dominam o inglês. Enfim ,seria legal pensar em formas de atrair essas pessoas que estão no stack ENG para cá. Uma aba de empregos seria um bom início

Comment: Mas fiz a pergunta também pq não sei se a Comunidade tem controle sobre esse tipo de coisa

Comment: Acredito que não tenha controle, mas só um moderador pode confirmar isso

Comment: Desculpa pessoal, não vi que estava duplicada.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar